# Content Length doesn't match write size

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

```
url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<ID>/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
request.head(url, function(e, r, b) {
      var headcontentlength = r.headers["content-length"];
}

request(url, function(e, r, b) {
    var getcontentlength = r.headers["content-length"];
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));

fs.stat(fileName, function(e, s) {
    var statscontentlength = s.size
}
```

Issue is that `headcontentlength !== getcontentlength !== statscontentlength`. 
None of these match.

For some realson the fileStream closes and doesn't match the content-length from the head request. Why would that be the case? Would the head and get request give different content-lengths? How can I over come this? Might have something to do with the soundcloud api?

Comment: Have you checked the `Content-Length` returned when issuing a GET request?

Comment: Wow they can all be different sometimes. I just check though and the get request content size doesn't alway match the size of the written file.

Comment: What if you try with the `http.get`/`http.request` built-in to node instead of the `request` module? Does that improve things or do you see the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible for the `Content-Length` to differ, although it's not supposed to. For example, I've seen some web servers (well, cache servers) set `Content-Length: -1` (which is already not legal) in response to a HEAD request but set the correct `Content-Length` for GET requests.